# JQuery stateful button function not binding to button in animated "Fadein" sign in form

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, button, stateful

I have a straight forward function that creates a nice fadein effect for my logo and sign in form on my login page as follows.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.LoginWrapper').css('opacity', '0')
    $('.SubtleEntrance').hide().fadeIn(1000, function(){
       $('.LoginWrapper').animate({
        opacity: 1
        }, 250, function() {
      })
     })
   });
```

The logo (id = SubtleEntrance) fades in and then the loginwrapper which contains a login for appears. Simple.

I am trying to implement a stateful submit button on the form with bootstrap

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#LoadingSignIn").on('click', function(event) {
    var btn = $('#LoadingSignIn').button('loading');
    setTimeout(function () {
        btn.button('reset');
       }, 3000);
     })
  });
```

If I have the code above to create the stateful effect for my button it works ONLY if I don't implement the loginwrapper effect.

I tried

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.LoginWrapper').css('opacity', '0')
    $('.SubtleEntrance').hide().fadeIn(1000, function(){
    $('.LoginWrapper').animate({
        opacity: 1
        }, 250, function() {
    })

      $("#LoadingSignIn").on('click', function(event) {
        var btn = $('#LoadingSignIn').button('loading');
        setTimeout(function () {
            btn.button('reset');
        }, 3000);
      })
    })
  });
```

But no luck. Clearly the stateful button function in someway is not getting bound the button when I have the loginwrapper effect. How to I combine this stateful button function with the animated loginwrapper so that it works?

edit:

Here is the forms basic structure (its a Rails app)

```
             <div class = "SubtleEntrance"><!--subtle entrance-->
                <div class = "logoHolder">
                  LOGO
                </div>
             </div>

             <div class ="LoginWrapper"><!--login wrapper-->

                <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name), html: { role: "form" }) do |f| %>
                <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, class: "form-control", :placeholder => "Email" %>
                <%= f.password_field :password, class: "form-control", :placeholder => "Password" %>
                <%= f.submit  t('.sign_in', :default => "Sign in"), class: "btn btn-primary", id: "LoadingSignIn", style: "width:100%", data: { "loading-text" => "Signing in..." } %>
                <% end %>

            </div>
```

Comment: Hi, can you post the HTML code for more details or create a fiddle?

Comment: Added form structure. Many thanks